# Don't understand the logic of const char*?

Tags: c++, reference

```
const char* str = &text; // that's how I was taught.
```

Why do we initialize const char* with a string and not a ref?

How is it that we initialize the pointer with a string of the "string" type and not with a & ref?

```
const char* str = "text"; // After all, should the pointer type be initialized with a reference or not?
```

Comment: `&text` is the address of the variable **text**.

Comment: you didn't understand the question

Comment: As I understand it, a separate memory is created for a string literal and that's where char * points to?

Comment: String literals are character arrays, and arrays implicitly convert to pointers to their first element whenever it is needed. If `text` is a `char [5]` (imagine `char text[5];`) then `const char* str = text;` will also work, just like the literal version.

Comment: it looks and sounds like magic... maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Do you understand *array to pointer decay*?

Comment: Basically, for historic reasons, `const char* str = "text"` is a special case of `const char* str = &text`, where the compiler essentially creates `text` in a read-only memory segment for string literals, and then assigns its address to `str`.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "string literal" and it's a special case

Comment: Also note that `&` in your example (`const char* str = &text;`) is **not** a _reference_ (and thus the _reference_ tag is not appropriate for this question). Here, `&` is the built-in _address-of operator_.

Comment: Specific clauses in the C++ standards (and in C standards, since C++ originally inherited this from C) allow initialisation of a `char` pointer using a string literal.   It works because a string literal is represented as a statically allocated array of `const char`, and initialising a pointer with a string literal has the effect of initialising that pointer as the address of the first character in that statically allocated array.   This is a special case in the standards (which was lobbied for by influential developers) - there is no direct equivalent for other types.

Answer (score 1):

> How is it that we initialize the pointer with a string

A string literal is an array of characters. All arrays will implicitly convert to a pointer to first element of the array. Thus, an array of characters will implicitly convert to a pointer to a character.